# Similarity in the musical scores of Star Wars and Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, star-wars, theme-music

Why is there such a similarity between the following two themes from Harry Potter and Star Wars?

1. Hedwig's theme (Harry Potter):
2. The Star Wars theme song, by John Williams:

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in Youtube links, and also changing your question slightly to make it more on-topic. Hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: oh thank you very much it's what i wanted to do but i didn't know how!

Comment: In what way are they more "similar" than any other music of an epic film composed by the same composer?

Comment: Much of Williams' works sound **very** similar to me. Some of Star Wars and Superman are darn near interchangeable. I'm of the opinion that he's over-rated.

Comment: I didn't know at first that the musics were composed by the same composer. Sorry if it wasn't very clear and thanks for the response :-)

Comment: I don't hear much similarity, beyond the most general sense.  Same composer, probably conducting the same instruments and possibly even many of the same musicians.  Aside from that, the music seems to be quite different to my ears.  YMMV.

Comment: @WadCheber Adding the info that JW composed Hedwig's theme makes my answer look silly! The OP didn't know that, and that piece of info was enough to _answer_ their query.

Comment: @randal'thor - You could have removed that while leaving in my title correction.

Comment: @MeatTrademark IMHO, it's _impossible_ to overrate John Williams. The man is a musical genius.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

John Williams wrote the music for both [Star Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_music) and [the first three Harry Potter films, including Hedwig's theme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_the_Harry_Potter_films), so it's understandable that they sound similar.

Comment: dont forget indiana jones

Comment: ok I din't know! thank you

Comment: @Nathou I just started watching the HP films a few days ago, and was surprised to see John Williams in the credits, so it's fresh in my mind. Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer (green tick on the left) if it's enough to solve your query! :-)